# AngularJS & UI - Can't access form outside when inside tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nested, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS version 1.0.5 and Angular UI (Bootstrap) 0.4.0.
I'm trying to integrate 2 features: the tabs of the UI and the forms of Angular.

I have nested forms.
One form (outerForm) wraps the whole tabset.
The other form (innerForm) resides within one tab.

I want to have a button, outside of the tabs, that will be enabled\disabled according to the validity of the **innerForm**!

When I try to access innerForm.$valid from outside the form itself, it does not work.

Here is a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sEz8TG?p=preview

Now, when I try the same with regular Bootstrap, it does seem to work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Somic4?p=preview

When the inner form resides within a regular div, I can access it from outside.
When I use the special 'tab' syntax of Angular UI, it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **tabset** directive is generating a local scope which isn't part of your outer forms scope.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js#L78

In the example that does work, your inner and outer form properties are within the same scope.  In order to prove this, I stripped out the outer tabset and tab tag directives [show here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RY3ieV?p=preview) and it works.  When you surround the markup with tabset directives, a new isolated scope is generated in which innerForm is part of.
.

To fix this, you can do a $watch for changes in the form followed by an $emit() (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) to communicate to the outer scope of the inner scope change in values and validity.

If you are using Chrome, get the [Batarang extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) which will show you your scope hierarchies

Comment: Also, make sure you upgrade to the latest Angular Bootstrap. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/574 Tab compilation was fixed which was causing several issues we were having with weird behavior on forms elements that were inside tabs.

Comment: Another option would be to shift the container of "form" object itself, like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568761/can-i-access-a-form-in-the-controller . If youre just looking a simple way to access form from base controller, despite the tabset - that's the simpliest option available.