# AngularJS check if form is valid in controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to check if a form is valid in a controller.

View:

```
<form novalidate=""
      name="createBusinessForm"
      ng-submit="setBusinessInformation()"
      class="css-form">
 <!-- fields -->
</form>
```

In my controller:

```
.controller(
    'BusinessCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, Business, BusinessService, 
              UserService, Photo)
    {

        if ($scope.createBusinessForm.$valid) {
            $scope.informationStatus = true;
        }

        ...
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you wrap it around the setBusinessInformation function within the controller?

Comment: code too fragmented to analyze what could be wrong...create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker that replicates problem. Is form within scope of `BusinessCtrl`? can't tell without seeing more

Comment: @matsko: No. I need to execute this code on controller initialization.

Comment: @charlietfl: There is not much more. I remove some code in order to simplify the example. Yes, the form should be in the scope of BusinessCtrl (the controller is set on routes in app.js. I add my solution in an answer below. But, I don´t know why is not working this way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have updated the controller to:

```
.controller('BusinessCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, Business, BusinessService, UserService, Photo) {
        $scope.$watch('createBusinessForm.$valid', function(newVal) {
            //$scope.valid = newVal;
            $scope.informationStatus = true;
        });
        ...
```

Comment: Also remember that - If the form is a Modal then remember to declare form name as dot notation eg: "data.theform" and access it in your controller as $scope.data.theform

Comment: This does not work for me. Please show how you get 'createBusinessForm' into the controller's $scope.

Comment: $scope things has gone, now a days we are using `vm` approach. can you create a plunker for same answer by using controller as syntax approach. I am not able to do it. It will be helpful for other as well who are looking for answer with today's context. Thanks

Answer (score 111):

Try this

in view:

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="submitForm(formName)">
 <!-- fields -->
</form>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(form){
  if(form.$valid) {
   // Code here if valid
  }
};
```

or

in view:

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="submitForm(formName.$valid)">
  <!-- fields -->
</form>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(formValid){
  if(formValid) {
    // Code here if valid
  }
};
```

Comment: What if I want to validate multiple buttons in a form?

Comment: this worked for me, but why `$scope.formName.$valid` results in undefined?

Comment: If you use ng-if then $scope.formName.$valid will not work and if you use ng-show then $scope.formName.$valid will work.

Comment: This should be the best answer, simple. But could you handle the form invalid ? How could you show to user what inputs are invalid ?

Comment: @ps0604 the `formName.$valid` can be accessed only in the template, if you want to access in the controller you need to create an object for that like `$scope.forms.formName` and in the template: `<form name="forms.formName">` [check this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27013197/3971521)

Comment: @NicolasLeucci you have `formName.inputName.$valid` for that. you can check the [input documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

Comment: @FahadMullaji the same as `NicolasLeucci` you need to check the [input documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

Comment: NIce clean answer.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another solution

Set a hidden scope variable in your html then you can use it from your controller:

```
<span style="display:none" >{{ formValid = myForm.$valid}}</span>
```

Here is the full working example:

```js
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.userType = 'guest';
  $scope.formValid = false;
  console.info('Ctrl init, no form.');
  
  $scope.$watch('myForm', function() {
    console.info('myForm watch');
    console.log($scope.formValid);
  });
  
  $scope.isFormValid = function() {
    //test the new scope variable
    console.log('form valid?: ', $scope.formValid);
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" ng-controller="myController">
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
  <tt>userType = {{userType}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br>
  
  
  /*-- Hidden Variable formValid to use in your controller --*/
  <span style="display:none" >{{ formValid = myForm.$valid}}</span>
  
  
  <br/>
  <button ng-click="isFormValid()">Check Valid</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `BusinessCtrl` is initialised before the `createBusinessForm`'s `FormController`.
Even if you have the `ngController` on the form won't work the way you wanted.
You can't help this (you can create your `ngControllerDirective`, and try to trick the priority.) this is how angularjs works.

See this plnkr for example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WYyu3raWQHkJ7XQzpDtY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I like to disable the save/submit button if the form is invalid:

```
<form name="ruleForm">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Priority</span>
        <input name="description" ng-model="vm.record.description" required>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button ng-click="vm.save()" ng-disabled="ruleForm.$invalid" class="md-primary md-raised">Save</md-button>
</form>
```