# How to use $valid with Angular example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

The [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) gives an example for custom form validation using `$asyncValidators`. Their example displays a message when the validation is pending or has an error. I want to display a message when the form has validated successfully.

To the best of my understanding, the [the form validation API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$valid) indicate that `$valid` returns a boolean, just like `$pending` or `$error`, and [the `$q` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) indicates that `resolve()` should make the form return valid.

[Here's a Plunker that doesn't work.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Mz8VRziHRWPs1DGwAHE?p=preview) Why doesn't the success message appear when the form is valid?

Comment: $pending and $error are objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
ng-show="form.name.$valid.username"
```

to:

```
ng-show="form.name.$valid"
```

$valid is a boolean variable not an object

here is a working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMCPxcZfPOEgAGKJSSx5?p=preview)

Comment: What makes it work is not the code diff you posted. In the plunker you changed `ng-show="form.name.$valid.username` to `ng-show="form.name.$valid` (no username) and that is enough to make it work.

Comment: $valid is a boolean variable not an object, there is no $valid.username.

Comment: Yes, exactly... which is why your previous answer (before you edited to this) was not a solution to the problem. The $valid.username -> $valid is.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here:

Checking form inside controller:

[AngularJS check if form is valid in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054055/angularjs-check-if-form-is-valid-in-controller)

If you want form validation succes message in the template use:

Success!

formName => name attribute in your form element