# angular, validate single input (not inside form)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to validate a single input to check numbers 1-99, I am wondering if I can do this in angular without having it wrapped in a form. Not a problem if it needs a form, just curious if it has to have it. Here's what I'm attempting -

```
<div class="errorMulti" ng-show="multiAdd.$error.maxlength">Error</div>
<input type='text' ng-model="multiAdd" placeholder='Number of levels to add 1-99' ng-maxlength="2">
```

Pretty straight forward, but doesn't seem to work. Any insight? thanks!

Comment: is there a reason to use input without a form? is any reason to do that?

Comment: None, just curious if you can.

Comment: can use `ng-form` also without form tag, see docs

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS <input> validation with no enclosing <form>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098584/angularjs-input-validation-with-no-enclosing-form)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<div ng-app>
   <form name="myform">
    <div class="errorMulti" ng-show="myform.multiAdd.$error.maxlength">Error</div>
    <input type='text' name="multiAdd" ng-model="multiAdd" placeholder='Number of levels to add 1-99' ng-maxlength="2">
    </form>
 </div>
```

Check the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/15ugz6j3/

Comment: I don't understand how this can be the accepted answer. The question is "How do I validate *outside* forms" and your answer is "wrap it in a form"?????