# Validate inputs in table row with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, require

I use [this lib](https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort) to create table on page.

Every row in this table can be edited. So if editMode is on, I show inputs at each column of row. Some of this inputs is required. I want to show red text "Required" or just red border if required field is empty. 
But problem - it's simple when I use form. But in my case I can't use forms.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25342654/3917754) isn't good for me, cause every row must have unique form-name for correct validation.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/r8d1uq0L/147/

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div name="myform-{{user.name}}" ng-form>
        <input type="text" ng-model='user.name' required name="field"/>
        <span class="error" ng-show="myform.field.$error.required">Too long!</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button ng-click="add()">
        Add
    </button>
</div>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.users = [{name:"1"}, {name:"2"}];
    $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.users.push({});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a dynamic form name, as `ng-repeat` does create new child scope on each iteration while drawing template on browser. So just keep name as `name="innerForm"` and use `innerForm.field.$error.required` to have validation over it.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div name="innerForm" ng-form>
        <input type="text" ng-model='user.name' required name="field"/>
        {{myform[$index]}}
        <span class="error" ng-show="innerForm.field.$error.required">Too long!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s3336g16/)

Comment: One question : In case I have `table` instead of `div`, can I make every cell of row as form like : `<td class="user-name" ng-form name="userNameForm">...</td> <td class="email" ng-form name="userEmailForm">...</td>` ? Is it good way?