# Can we use angular input validation without form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Is there a way to use angular input validation without form. See angular [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oLwkDeAehjZYuLIYdlLO?p=preview). When I change `<form name="myForm">` by `<div name="myForm">` the validation does not work anymore.

HTML :

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
     User name:
     <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
  </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">
     Required!</span>
  </div>
  <label>
     Last name:
     <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.last" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
  </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the reason to remove the `form`?

Comment: My real use of input is inside an input component with `angular.module('myModule').component('myInput')` which will be called in a parent form component and I don't want to put a form in a form

Comment: @Mouss So you just want an input validation? `ng-model` makes also validation possible...

Comment: @Mikey ng-model doesn't respond with my needs because I have like 20 angular directive for specific input form validation and I don't want to rewrite all those validation directives with ng-model

Comment: You can refer [Form Validation without Form Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098584/angularjs-input-validation-with-no-enclosing-form) by Silvio Lucas

Comment: you can use ng-form directive in div. This will work. check the link https://plnkr.co/edit/Z090iiwrinMoFHfP2vyA?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have form directive because ngModel searches its controller in order to register itself and leverage validation capabilities.

If for layout reasons you can't have form tag (nested `<form>` tags are invalid) then you can use [ngForm](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) directive to achieve the same effect:

```
<ng-form name="myForm">
  <label>
     User name:
     <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
  </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">
     Required!</span>
  </div>
  <label>
     Last name:
     <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.last"
     ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
  </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.minlength">
      Too short!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">
      Too long!</span>
  </div>
</ng-form>
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/WlCqNBWtqiGerkQy0Wad?p=preview

Comment: Thanx @dfsq, when you say > ngModel searches its controller in order to register itself and leverage validation capabilities. You mean ngModel search form's controller?

Comment: I mean `<input ng-model="asdfa" name="something">`. So ngModel directive searches for `ngForm` directive waling up the DOM tree. When it find it it registers itself with it. Something like `ngFormController.addControl(...)`.