# Access to form data that submitted by an unknown source

Tags: angularjs, post, angularjs-controller

**Scenario:**
Another web application get a link from my web app and then POST some data to the link, like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/mylink">
    <input type="hidden" name="data1" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data2" value="2" />
    <input type='submit' value="submit" />
</form>
```

I know there are two parameters data1 and data2 in POST data and nothing else.

**Question:**
How can I access to this data in Controller?
Because this form submitted in another web application so there is not ng-model directive and or ng-click="submit(customerForm)". I don't know even what is form's name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access a form in the controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568761/can-i-access-a-form-in-the-controller)

Comment: isherwood, I think this question is different. I added some details.