# Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a statistics page using angular.

When I submit the form it throws the error Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined.

Here is the html:

```
<form name="statsForm" ng-submit="quoteRequestsKpi()" novalidate>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="form-group" show-errors="{ showSuccess: true }">
        <label for="month">Month</label>
        <select name="month" id="month" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="statsIn.month">
          <option value="0">January</option>
          <option value="1">February</option>
          ...
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="form-group" show-errors="{ showSuccess: true }">
        <label for="year">Year</label>
        <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="statsIn.year">
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="go" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the js code :

```
controllers.controller('StatsController', [
'$scope', 'growl', 'appService',
function($scope, growl, appService) {
    var logger = log4javascript.getLogger('Stats');

    logger.debug('StatsController');

    /**
     */
    $scope.statsIn = {
        month : null,
        year : '2017'
    };

    /**
     */
    $scope.$on(EVENT_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS, function() {
        logger.debug(EVENT_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS);

        $scope.init();
    });

    /**
     */
    $scope.quoteRequestsKpi = function() {
        logger.debug('quoteRequestsKpi');

        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity');

        if ($scope.statsForm.$invalid) {
            return;
        }

        appService.quoteRequestsKpi($scope.kpiIn).then(function(data) {
            if (data.status == SUCCESS) {

                $scope.quoteRequestKpis = data.quoteRequestKpis;
            } else {
                logger.warn('quoteRequestsKpi: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.ensureUserIsAuthenticated();
}]);
```

Does anyone know why I am getting an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your form is undefined inside your controller. You have to create a reference to the form in your controller.

This could be accomplished either by using `controllerAs` syntax:

e.g.

In the view:

```
 <div ng-controller="StatsController as vm">
  <form name="vm.statsForm">
   <!--Input Fields...-->
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.statsForm// This is a reference to your form.
```

Or if you wish to inject `$scope` in the controller, then the answer of how to access your form can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568761/can-i-access-a-form-in-the-controller/#answer-24123379).

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LaofxvoVe2udEuWTKcIg?p=preview).