# ng-form inside ng-repeat not updating subform.$submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-forms

I am trying create forms inside ng-repeat, everything is working fine except submit button. Submit button placed in main form it is common for all sub forms. 
If the submit button is clicked `mainForm.$submitted` gets updated but `userForm.$submitted` dose not changing. Is there any work around for that ?

```js
 angular.module("sampleApp", [])
   .controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.users = [{},{}];
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
  <form name="mainForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="school" ng-model="school" required>
      main form input valid=>{{mainForm.school.$valid}}
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <ng-form name="userForm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="name" required>
        sub form input valid=>{{userForm.name.$valid}} | sub form submit=>{{userForm.$submitted}}
      </ng-form>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    Form valid=>{{mainForm.$valid}} | Main From submit => {{mainForm.$submitted}}
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Comment: have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Intro

So, I added a `ng-click` handler to the button so that you set the submitted status of the internal form as well.

The only difficult I had was to actually get the form reference, but I added the function `$scope.setUserForm` which is called with an `ng-init`. The solution pattern is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862411/1688441

Also, please keep in mind you need an array of userForms to keep the references. On click you iterate through these elements and set the submitted.

### Code

```js
 angular.module("sampleApp", [])
 .controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope) {

     $scope.UserForms = [];
     $scope.setUserForm = function(form) {
         $scope.UserForm = form;
         $scope.UserForms.push(form);
     }

     $scope.forms = {};
     $scope.users = [{}, {}];

     $scope.handleClick = function() {

         $scope.UserForms.forEach(function(element) {
             element.$submitted = true;
         });

     };

 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
  <form name="mainForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="school" ng-model="school" required>
      input valid=>{{mainForm.school.$valid}}
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <ng-form name="userForm">
 <div ng-init="setUserForm(userForm);"></div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="name" required>
        input valid=>{{userForm.name.$valid}} | form submit=>{{userForm.$submitted}}
      </ng-form>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="handleClick()">Submit</button>
    Form valid=>{{mainForm.$valid}} | From submit => {{mainForm.$submitted}}
  </form>
  
</div>
```